# How to create custom folders inside WordPress uploads folder without any plugins?

Tags: wordpress, media-library

I want to create custom folders without using any plugins. I go to "wp-content/uploads" and create a new folder inside, but it doesn't appear online. How do I make it appear? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't appear online"? Online where exactly?

Comment: In WordPress dashboard > media library

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to create a custom folder in the wp-uploads folder but however you need a plugin to make them appear on your website.

You can create your custom folder using your hosting file manager or FTP Client, you can also upload your desired files into this folder using the same method.

To make all your files appear on your WordPress media library, you need to install the "Add from server" plugin. Once you have registered all your file to your media library db, you can uninstall the plugin without any effect.